# objective-c : App crashes in archiveRootObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

```
Error content:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Dmain.LDevice encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f811c717ca0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

The actual data is in this format taken and saved as `NSMutableArray`.

```
<Dmain.LDevice: 0x7fa9f5761fc0>,
```

I tried to save it as `NSUserDefault` and I was looking for another way because App Crash occurred.

During searching, we encode using `NSCoding` and found a way to use decoding.

However, the same error as the above error will continue to occur.

Below is the source I wrote.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *stringRootPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/metaDeviceList"];

ArchiveData *archiveData = [ArchiveData new];

archiveData.metaDeviceList = [_metaDeviceList mutableCopy];

NSMutableData *mutableData = [NSMutableData new];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:mutableData];

[archiver encodeObject:archiveData forKey:@"metaDeviceList"];   // App crush
[archiver finishEncoding];

//  [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:archiveData toFile:stringRootPath];  // App crush

[mutableData writeToFile:stringRootPath atomically:YES];
```

And the source content of ArchiveData.

```
(ArchiveData.h)


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ArchiveData : NSObject <NSObject,NSCoding>
{
    NSObject *_metaDeviceList;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *metaDeviceList;

@end



(ArchiveData.m)

#import "ArchiveData.h"

@implementation ArchiveData

- (void)dealloc{
    [self setMetaDeviceList:nil];
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(nonnull NSCoder *)aCoder {

    [aCoder encodeObject:self.metaDeviceList forKey:@"metaDeviceList"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(nonnull NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {

        self.metaDeviceList = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"metaDeviceList"];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

What is the problem? Please let me know how to fix it! Please…

Comment: In `encodeWithCoder:` of `ArchiveData`, you are doing [aCoder encodeObject:self.metaDeviceList forKey:@"metaDeviceList"]`. In order to do so, `metaDeviceList` class needs to conforms too to `NSCoding`.

Comment: @Larme - Thanks for your help. Have a happy day.